# Block navigation when client hits in address bar using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Hello i have to stop navigation when user types /pricing in address bar
and navigate only when $location.path("/pricing") is fired

```
when("/pricing", {
        templateUrl: "app/components/Pricing/pricing.html",
    })
```

how to do this? please help me

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is set a `flag` and navigate only when the flag is `true` else prevent default action in `locationChangeStart`.

```
yourApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
       if($location.path() == '/pricing' && !flag) 
         event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the navigation from happening
      }
    );
  }]);
```